# Regular expression as delimiter in explode()

Tags: php, arrays, regex, explode

So I have a string which I'm turning into an array but I want to separate each word using a regex. I'm matching a whole word using the below function.

```
function substr_count_array($haystack, $needle)
{
     $initial = 0;
     $bits = explode(' ', $haystack);

     foreach ($needle as $substring) 
     {
        if (!in_array($substring, $bits))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $initial += substr_count($haystack, $substring);
     }

     return $initial;
}
```

The problem is that it matches the string `animal` for example but not `animals`. And if I do a partial match like this:

```
function substr_count_array2($haystack, $needle)
{
     $initial = 0;

     foreach ($needle as $substring) 
     {
          $initial += substr_count($haystack, $substring);
     }

     return $initial;
}
```

It also matches, let's say, `a` since it's contained withing the word `animals` and returns `2`. How do I `explode()` using a regular expression as a delimiter so that I may, for example, match every string that has a length of 5-7 characters?

Explained simpler:

```
$animals = array('cat','dog','bird');
$toString = implode(' ', $animals);
$data = array('a');

echo substr_count_array($toString, $data);
```

If I search for a character such as `a`, it gets through the check and validates as a legit value because `a` is contained within the first element. But if I match whole words exploded by a space, it omits them if they are not separated by a space. Thus, I need to separate with a regular expression that matches anything **AFTER** the string that is to be matched.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply put, you need to use [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) instead of `explode`.

While `explode` will split on constant values, `preg_split` will split based on a regular expression.

In your case, it would probably be best to split on non-word characters `\W+`, then manually filter the results for length.

Comment: Something like this? `preg_split('(.+?)', $haystack);`

Comment: @JessieStalk - Not quite.  The regular expression you pass to `preg_split` is the pattern the string is *split* on, not what strings you want to *keep*.  If you're trying to keep the words in your input, you should split on non-word characters: `preg_split('/\W+/', $haystack)`

Comment: Thanks for you time and effort :)